# forcing a page break in the middle of a long footnote in LaTeX

Tags: footnotes

My supervisor has a LaTeX page that has a small amount of body
text and a long footnote consisting of two paragraphs. Is there 
any way to force the footnote to break across two pages 
and to choose the break point to be between the two 
paragraphs.

I did some google searches related to this and most people 
seemed to have the opposite problem; they didn’t want 
a long footnote to be broken across two pages.

But from one google result, it might help to put

\interfootnotelinepenalty=0

in the preamble. But that doesn’t solve the problem of 
choosing the break point to be between the two 
paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

In all probability, [Ulrike’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374491/69818) is what you really want.  However, in order to do *literally* what your question asks for, that is, to *force* a page break between two paragraphs of a footnote (for example, because you don’t want the footnote to take up so much vertical space on that particular page), you should simply write

```
\vspace{\maxdimen}
```

between the two paragraphs in question.  The two methods (Ulrike’s and this one) can also be combined:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

Blah blah.\footnote{\interlinepenalty = 10000
\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{\maxdimen}

\lipsum[3-4]
}

\end{document}
```

Note that replacing

```
\vspace{\maxdimen}
```

with

```
\pagebreak[4]
```

is not guaranteed to work in every situation, not even if you use

```
\par \penalty -1000000000
```

in lieu of `\pagebreak[4]`.  The reason is explained on p. 123 of *The TeXbook*: whenever Step 3 applies, Step 4 is not even tried.

More generally, you could *force* a page break after a certain line in a footnote by placing

```
\vadjust{\vskip\maxdimen}
```

somewhere on that line; this will overcome any other setting that might be in force.  For example:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

Blah blah.\footnote{\interlinepenalty = 10000 \clubpenalty = 10000
\lipsum[1-2]

I~want this footnote to be broken across pages right after the line that
contains \emph{this}\vadjust{\vskip\maxdimen} word.  \lipsum*[3]

\lipsum[4]
}

\end{document}
```

Finally, it should be noted that, if the problem is that you want to limit the vertical space on a page devoted to footnotes, you can do so by setting the value of a length that can be named as `\dimen\footins`.  For example,

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\setlength{\dimen\footins}{200pt}

Blah blah.\footnote{\lipsum[1-4]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `\interlinepenalty10000` in the footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{10cm}
blalbl\footnote{\interlinepenalty10000 \lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]