# footnote does not break across pages

Tags: amsmath, footnotes, page-breaking, txfonts

I have a long footnote containing several equations (source below). LaTeX refuses to break the footnote over a page, despite `\interfootnotelinepenalty=0`, and as a consequence creates an almost empty page preceding the text with the footnote. I found that the problem disappears if I don't `usepackage{txfonts}`.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374517/14552) shows how to force a page break *at a particular point in the footnote*, and yes that works in my example. However, I want LaTeX to automatically and sensibly break the footnote as it does when not `usepackage{txfonts}`.

How can achieve this?

```
% source code (edited after first answer attempt didn't solve problem)
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphics}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=0

\newcommand*{\p}         {\partial}
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]  {\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand*{\pdiff}[2]  {\frac{\p{#1}}{\p{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote.
This just some text preceding the footnote\footnote
{It is an instructive but non-trivial exercise to prove this result directly from the definition and without Euler's theorem. Taking the derivative with respect to the position of particle $i$ yields its force:
\[
    \vec{F}_i = - \pdiff{U}{\vec{r}_i} =
    - \frac{G}{2}\sum_{j,k} \frac{m_{\!j}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
    \frac{\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_k|}
    (\delta_{i\!j}-\delta_{ik})
\]
where we have used $\p|\vec{r}|/\p\vec{r}=\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|$. Using the defining property of the Kronecker delta gives
\[
    \vec{F}_i = 
    - \frac{G}{2}
    \left[\sum_{k} \frac{m_{i}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
                   \frac{\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|} -
          \sum_{j} \frac{m_{\!j}\,m_i}{|\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_i|^2}
                   \frac{\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_i}{|\vec{r}_{\!j}-\vec{r}_i|}
    \right].
\]
Since the sum index is just a dummy variable, we see that the two terms are identical,
i.e.
\[
    \vec{F}_i = - G \sum_{k} \frac{m_{i}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
                          \frac{\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|}.
\]
We can now compute the virial of the system:
\[
    \sum_i\vec{F}_i\cdot\vec{r}_i =
    -G\sum_{i,k}
    \frac{m_{i}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
    \frac{\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|}\cdot\vec{r}_i.
\]
Consider the same expression with the summation indices $i$ and $k$ swapped
\[
    \sum_i\vec{F}_i\cdot\vec{r}_i =
    -G\sum_{i,k}
    \frac{m_k\,m_i}{|\vec{r}_k-\vec{r}_i|^2}
    \frac{\vec{r}_k-\vec{r}_i}{|\vec{r}_k-\vec{r}_i|}\cdot\vec{r}_k 
    =  G\sum_{i,k}  \label{eq:U:grav:2}
    \frac{m_i\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
    \frac{\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_k|}\cdot\vec{r}_k,
\]
where the second equality follows from $\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_k = -(\vec{r}_k-\vec{r}_i)$.
Adding this to the previous form,
\[
    \sum_i\vec{F}_i\cdot\vec{r}_i =
    - \frac{G}{2} \sum_{i,k}\frac{m_{i}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|^2}
    \frac{\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|}\cdot(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_k)
    = -\frac{G}{2}
    \sum_{i,k}\frac{m_{i}\,m_k}{|\vec{r}_{i}-\vec{r}_k|}
    = U.
\]
}
This is just some text following the footnote.
This is just some text following the footnote.
This is just some text following the footnote.
This is just some text following the footnote.

\end{document}
```

Sorry, I didn't manages to create a shorter example.

Comment: The `fleqn` package is obsolete. If you don't load it, you'll experience an important side-benefit: LaTeX can suddenly 'find' page breaks in a long footnote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions/observations:

- The main thing you must do in order for LaTeX to be able to create page breaks  inside a long footnote is to stop loading the `fleqn` package. Aside: Since you're specifying the document class option `fleqn` (which will be passed to the `amsmath` package), there can't be a valid reason for loading the obsolete `fleqn` package anyway.
- (Optional) Instead of loading the nearly-obsolete `txfonts` package, consider loading the more recent `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. You'll find that the newer packages produce better-spaced math expressions.

Comment: Strange things happen. Not loading `fleqn` sure fixes the issue with my posted source code. However, it does not with my real code, even with *exactly* the same preamble. How come? Also, using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` in stead of `txfonts` make no difference to this problem.

Comment: @Walter - I'm afraid that as I don't have access to your 'real code', I'm not in a position to offer a diagnosis, let alone a cure. (Do you maybe want to post the 'real code', including the full preamble?) Replacing `txfonts` with the `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` pair was not meant as a cure of the the failure-to-create-a-pagebreak issue; instead, it was meant as a general suggestion.

Comment: I cannot, for obvious reasons, post the real code. Btw, I prefer the spacing produced by `txfonts` over that produced by `newtxmath` for multiple indices as in `\delta_{\alpha\beta}`: the space between the α and β is smaller, which I prefer.

Comment: Hi Mico, I could actually reproduce the problem with the simple source code: it suffices to insert a `\section{A}` command and the problem remains despite not loading `fleqn`.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX doesn't refuse to break the footnote: If you change it a bit and add e.g. 1-3 more lines of text it works. Also the `\section` in itself is not really the problem, but it changes the length of the text and so changes the page breaking.

The main problem is that you are putting too many large objects into the footnote. You can ameliorate the situation in some cases (not all!) by allowing a break before a display math, but imho it would be much better to avoid such footnotes -- put the proof in the appendix.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@footnotetext{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize \predisplaypenalty=-100 }{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Walter: The claim made in the first paragraph of this answer can be proved by examining the trace produced by `\tracingoutput=1`: you’ll see that TeX tries to split the footnote before the last displayed equation, but refrains from doing so because, in the default settings, taking a page break before a displayed equation is not allowed.